# Entity Framework 5 rc Code First Specifying Schema to create tables under?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Using EF 5 RC what is the proper way to specify what schema tables are created under while using the Code First process?
I have tried:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Metric>().ToTable("Metrics", "Dashboard");
    }
```

But the SQL script created doesn't recognize the schema and makes all the tables under the dbo schema.

TIA

J

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you right click on the EDMX designer surface and go to properties you can set the schema for that diagram. So if you want to put different entities/tables in different schemas you have to keep them on seperate design surfaces.

Comment: How is this the correct answer ? Isnt that answer based on model approach ?